# jQuery Horizontal Accordion

Tags: jquery, horizontal-accordion

I'm looking for a very simple-to-implement horizontal accordion and was wondering what others are using.

[This is the kind of thing I'm looking for](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/accordion-common/accordion.html).

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902973/horizontal-and-vertical-accordion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one you suggested looks very easy to implement... http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jQuery-common-accordion

Answer (score 0):

Try thus: http://ajaxian.com/archives/horizontal-accordion-20-for-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Z-Accordion looks promising as well - it's responsive, easy to implement, free and open source.

zAccordion is supported in Internet Explorer 8 and the latest builds of Firefox, Chrome, and Safari.

Have a look on the website
http://www.armagost.com/zaccordion/